# Getting a sequence, ignoring Nulls

Tags: sql, hana

I have the following table, where ? are Null values.

```
X14 X13 X12 X11 X10 X9  X8  X7  X6
9   ?   ?   ?   ?   1   17  14  ?
8   9   ?   ?   ?   1   17  14  ?
1   8   9   ?   ?   1   17  14  ?
?   1   8   1   9   1   17  14  ?
?   ?   1   ?   9   1   17  14  ?
?   ?   ?   ?   ?   8   9   2   14
```

I was trying to get the sequences of values [x(n),x(n-1),...] across columns, without the Nulls.

The intended result would be the following:

```
y   x1  x2  x3
9   1   17  14
8   9   1   17
1   8   9   1
1   8   1   9
1   9   1   17
8   9   2   14
```

I tried to perform COALESCE(X14,COALESCE(X13,...)) but it doesn't work that well as it gets stuck on the first non-null value it finds.

Is there anything that I can do to skip the Nulls and get the correct sequence?
The database is Hana, but share your answer regardless - I might be able to adapt it. :)

Best,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create column  TABLE xvals (X14 INT,X13 INT,X12 INT,X11 INT,X10 INT,X9 INT,X8 INT,X7 INT,X6 INT);

INSERT INTO xvals (
select 9,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,17,14,NULL from dummy UNION ALL
select 8,9,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,17,14,NULL from dummy UNION ALL
select 1,8,9,NULL,NULL,1,17,14,NULL from dummy UNION ALL
select NULL,1,8,1,9,1,17,14,NULL from dummy UNION ALL
select NULL,NULL,1,NULL,9,1,17,14,NULL from dummy UNION ALL
select NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8,9,2,14 from dummy 
);

with aschar as (
    select ifnull(to_varchar(X14)||'x', '') ||
           ifnull(to_varchar(X13)||'x', '') ||
           ifnull(to_varchar(X12)||'x', '') ||
           ifnull(to_varchar(X11)||'x', '') ||         
           ifnull(to_varchar(X10)||'x', '') ||         
           ifnull(to_varchar(X9)||'x', '') ||
           ifnull(to_varchar(X8)||'x', '') ||
           ifnull(to_varchar(X7)||'x', '') ||
           ifnull(to_varchar(X6)||'x', '')           
           cval
    from xvals)

select  SUBSTR_REGEXPR ('[[:digit:]]+' in cval occurrence 1)
            as y,
        SUBSTR_REGEXPR ('[[:digit:]]+' in cval occurrence 2)
            as x1,
        SUBSTR_REGEXPR ('[[:digit:]]+' in cval occurrence 3)
            as x2,
        SUBSTR_REGEXPR ('[[:digit:]]+' in cval occurrence 4)
            as x3

from aschar

Y   X1  X2  X3
9   1   17  14
8   9   1   17
1   8   9   1 
1   8   1   9 
1   9   1   17
8   9   2   14
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably to specific with SQL Server, but there was a trick with XML:

XML - by default - just ommits the `NULLs`.

Other databases (in your case *hana*) will not support this, but you might get an idea...

This would bring up the result you need.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(X14 INT,X13 INT,X12 INT,X11 INT,X10 INT,X9 INT,X8 INT,X7 INT,X6 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (9,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,17,14,NULL)
,(8,9,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,17,14,NULL)
,(1,8,9,NULL,NULL,1,17,14,NULL)
,(NULL,1,8,1,9,1,17,14,NULL)
,(NULL,NULL,1,NULL,9,1,17,14,NULL)
,(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8,9,2,14);

WITH Casted AS
(SELECT
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM @tbl
        FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
    ) AS AsXml
)
SELECT r.value('*[1]','int') AS y
      ,r.value('*[2]','int') AS x1
      ,r.value('*[3]','int') AS x2
      ,r.value('*[4]','int') AS x3
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/row') AS A(r)
```

Comment: Plus1 Simply elegant

Answer (score 0):

Putting them in four separate columns is difficult.  You could concatenate the valid values into a single list:

```
select (case when x14 is not null then x14 || ';' else '' end) ||
       (case when x13 is not null then x13 || ';' else '' end) ||
       . . .
```